# Turning nested jQuery Promises into flat code structure using .done() and .then()

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

This code uses jQuery promises in combination with callbacks does the following:

1. Saves Group UUID to server using `storeGroupOnServer()`
2. Creates a DOM element for the group using `createGroupDomNode()`
3. Creates child elements for each image, using `createNewChildDomNode()`

How can this be written more flat (avoiding the nesting), using `.then()`?

```
var groupPromise = groupInstance.promise();
var arrayOfFiles = groupInstance.files();

groupPromise.done(function(fileGroupInfo) {
    storeGroupOnServer(fileGroupInfo.uuid, function(groupid){

        createGroupDomNode(groupid, function(groupnode){

            $.each(arrayOfFiles, function(i, file) {
                file.done(function(fileInfo) {
                    createNewChildDomNode(fileInfo.cdnUrl, groupnode);
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

**Step 1: `storeGroupOnServer()`:**

```
storeGroupOnServer = function(uuid, callback) {
    $.post('saveGroup.php', {uuid:uuid},
    function(data) {
        callback(data.groupid);
    },'json');
};
```

**Step 2: `createGroupDomNode()`:**

```
createGroupDomNode = function(groupid, callback) {
    var cloner = $('#cloner');
    var newnode = cloner.clone(true);
    newnode.attr('id',groupid);
    newnode.removeClass('hide');
    cloner.after(newnode);
    callback(newnode);
}
```

**Step 3: `createNewChildDomNode()`:**

```
function createNewChildDomNode(imgpath, groupdom){
    imgnode = $('<img/>').attr('src',imgpath);
    picnode = $('<picture/>').append(imgnode);
    $(groupdom).first().prepend(picnode);
}
```

Comment: Where is `arrayOfFiles` defined?

Comment: @guest271314 Is defined outside the function, I've added it for completeness.

Answer (score 1):

You can substitute `return`ing `Promise` objects from functions for using callbacks as parameters to function, to chain `.then()` and `.catch()`. `Array.prototype.map()` and `Promise.all()` can be substituted for `jQuery.each()` which does not await the fulfillment of `Promise` objects iterated.

Which requires `return`ing the jQuery promise object from `storeGroupOnServer`

```
storeGroupOnServer = function(uuid, callback) {
    return $.post('saveGroup.php', {uuid:uuid},'json')
           .then(function(data) {
             return data.groupid;
           });
};
```

and returning a jQuery promise object of `Promise` from `createGroupDomNode`

```
createGroupDomNode = function(groupid, callback) {
    var cloner = $('#cloner');
    var newnode = cloner.clone(true);
    newnode.attr('id',groupid);
    newnode.removeClass('hide');
    cloner.after(newnode);
    return $.Deferred().resolve(newnode);
}
```

and awaiting `<img>` element `load` event

```
function createNewChildDomNode(imgpath, groupdom){
    return $.Deferred(function(dfd) {
             imgnode = $('<img/>')
                       .on("load", dfd.resolve)
                       .on("error", dfd.reject)
                       .attr('src',imgpath);
             picnode = $('<picture/>').append(imgnode);
             $(groupdom).first().prepend(picnode);
           }).promise();
}
```

For example

```js
const data = {
  uuid: {
    1: 4,
    2: 5,
    3: 6
  }
};
const response = {
  4: "a",
  5: "b",
  6: "c"
};

const groupPromise = Promise.resolve(data.uuid[1]); // initial `Promise`
const arrayOfFiles = [Promise.resolve({
  fileInfo: {
    cdnUrl: 10
  }
}), Promise.resolve({
  fileInfo: {
    cdnUrl: 20
  }
}), Promise.resolve({
  fileInfo: {
    cdnUrl: 30
  }
})];

const storeGroupOnServer = (uuid) => {
  console.log({
    uuid
  });
  // `return` response `Promise`
  return Promise.resolve(response[uuid])
};

const createGroupDomNode = (groupid) => {
  console.log({
    groupid
  });
  // `return` `groupid`
  return Promise.resolve(groupid)
};
const createNewChildDomNode = (groupdom, {
  // destructure `cdnUrl` define as `imgpath`
  fileInfo: {
    cdnUrl: imgpath 
  }
}) => {
  console.log({
    imgpath,
    groupdom
  });
  // process `<img>` elements here
  // `return` resolved or rejected `Promise` 
  // at `load` or `error` event
  return Promise.resolve("done processing " + imgpath)
};
let handleFiles = (groupnode, file) => {
  console.log({
    groupnode,
    file
  });
  // handle each `file` `Promise`, pass `group` node to 
  // function passed to `.then()`
  return file.then(createNewChildDomNode.bind(null, groupnode))
};
const handleGroupDomNodes = (groupnode) => {
  console.log({
    groupnode
  });
  // use `Promise.all()`, `.map()` to process array of `Promise` objects
  return Promise.all(
    arrayOfFiles.map(handleFiles.bind(null, groupnode))
  )
};

groupPromise
.then(storeGroupOnServer)
.then(createGroupDomNode)
.then(handleGroupDomNodes)
.then(complete => console.log(complete)) // to illustrate chain completes
.catch(err => console.error(err)); // handle errors in chain
```